# Матрица в консоли на С

Tags: c, c++

Всем привет! Смотрите есть консоль, как мне сделать с нее матрицу? Т.е. получить скажем координаты 20х20...
Ввожу 5:12 и на этой точке в матрице ставится например точка. Даже не знаю куда копать...

Вот набросал что бы понятнее было:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int i; 
  int j;     
  for(i = 1; i<=20; i++)
  {
    for(j = 1; j<=20; j++)
    {
       printf(".");
    }   
    printf(".\n");

  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Смотрите ncurses

Comment: OC какая ? А совсем просто - там где не точка, выводите пробел.

Comment: > Смотрите ncurses

+1024

Answer (score 1):

См. [gotoxy](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/spr/220.php) перемещайте курсор, печатайте что нужно.

Comment: для windows:

   #include <windows.h> 

   void gotoxy(int x, int y)
   {
      COORD coord;
      coord.X = x;
      coord.Y = y;
      SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    }

Comment: туда же 

    int wherex()
    {
      CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
      GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &info);
      return info.dwCursorPosition.X;
    }
 
    int wherey()
    {
      CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
      GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &info);
      return info.dwCursorPosition.Y;
    }

гуглится все очень просто.

А вот для замены одного символа перерисовывать всю консоль, мягко говоря, через чур.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по getch() в конце Вам нужно для Винды.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

main ()
{
  system ("cls");
  COORD position = {0,0}; //позиция x (столбец) и y (строка)
  HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
  putchar('+');
  position.X =   position.Y = 10;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
  putchar('+');
  position.X =   position.Y = 20;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
  putchar('+');
  position.X = 70;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
  putchar('@');
}
```

Запускал в 7-ке окошке консоли (cmd) и PowerShell.

Comment: в питона играем? ;) у нас сначала играли в "жизнь", потом питон уже был...

Comment: Не понял, в какого питона ? Жизнь знаю, писал когда-то (еще на АЦПУ ЕС ЭВМ). 

Просто нагуглил по "windows консоль перемещение курсора" SetConsoleCursorPosition и проверил, пока туда-сюда, записал, а смотрю тут уже Ваш ответ.

Comment: питон растет если съедает еду. + - еда. @ - голова питона )

Comment: Понятно, я где-то видел такую игрушку. 

Он жрет, растет и надо им стрелочками управлять, чтобы себя не ел ? Так ?

Надо же, а ведь случайно символы выбирал.

Comment: @avp Ваш питон отображался на АЦПУ? Круто!

Comment: @alexlz, Вы бы еще добавили - и управлялся подкладыванием новых перфокарт.

Нет, конечно, жизнь. Насколько помню, задавал начальную конфигурацию и количество картинок.

Comment: До терминалов с ЭЛТ на диком Западе активно использовались терминалы с выводом на бумагу: пишущие машинки или другие устройства. Кстати, известный язык APL родом оттуда. Его мудрёные операции получались печатью одного знака, сдвигом каретки назад и печатью следующего.

Answer (score 0):

> См. gotoxy перемещайте курсор, печатайте что нужно.

### ^Эта функция далеко не везде - в винде, например, ее нет.

```
    Можно пойти 2 путями - или простым, или с массивом)
    вариант с массивом - как - то так - 
    ----------

    > int main()
    > {
    > unsigned char matrix[20][20]={' '};
    > int x,y,i,j;  
    > puts("Enter x and y coordinates:");  
    > printf("x: "); scanf("%d",&x);  
    > printf("y: "); scanf("%d",&y);      
    > if(x<0||y<0||x>20||y>20)
    > {   
    >   puts("Wrong number!"); 
    >   return 1;  
    > }
    > matrix[y][x]='.'; 
      for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    >     {
            for(j=0;j<20;j++) printf("%c ",matrix[i][j]);
    >     printf("\n");
    >     }
    > return 0;
    > }
    ----------
    Ну или вариант без массива, который проще(в случае, если после этого матрицу использовать не нужно).
    ----------
    int main()
    > {
    > int x,y,i,j;  
    > puts("Enter x and y coordinates:");  
    > printf("x: "); scanf("%d",&x);  
    > printf("y: "); scanf("%d",&y);      
    > if(x<0||y<0||x>20||y>20)
    > {   
    >   puts("Wrong number!"); 
    >   return 1;  
    > }
    > for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    > {
    >     for(j=0;j<20;j++)
    >        {
    >            if(i==y&&j==x) printf(". ");
    >            else printf("  ");
    >        }
    >      printf("\n");
    > }
    > return 0;
    > }
    > 
    ----------
```

Comment: ну не забыть подключить stdio.h ,conio.h и прописать что-нибудь вроде "getch();" в конце.

Comment: Сами себе противоречите, если с изрядной долей пуризма предположить, что в виндах нет `gotoxy`, то и `getch` там тоже быть не может.

Comment: так getch() есть в conio, а вот gotoxy(x,y) там вроде как нет.

Comment: Разные подходы, господа)
я как-то привык обходиться без системных функций (getch() не в счет).
Возможно, в этом моя ошибка, не спорю.

Comment: @Luchnik95 а puts и printf входят в число разрешённых?